# Is there a way in Dart to access attributes dynamically, like with Javascript objects-as-hashes?

Tags: dart

For example, in javascript I might have a function:

```
this.getPrettyAttr = function(attr){
    return attr + " is: " + this[attr];
}
```

Where attr is a string, to get things like:

> "strength is 7", "height is 5", "power is 9001", "name is Betty"

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Dart, or am I stuck doing things manually again?

Comment: Nope, that other one was specifically for DOM stuff. THOUGH one comment did specify that Dart would only do it for DOM and not generic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mirrors for this. Here's an article for reference: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/reflection-with-mirrors

In your case, you could write something like:

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

getPrettyAttr(Object x, Symbol attr) {
  var mirror = reflect(x);
  return '$attr is: ${mirror.getField(attr)}';
}
```

However, there is a caveat to using mirrors in Dart. If your program is only server side (i.e., you use `dart:io`) then mirrors are fine. But if your program is being compiled to JavaScript, mirrors can bloat your app, since the compiler has no way to know which functions might be called in your app.